# ¿Cuál es la manera más rápida de matar un proceso en Windows?

Tags: c, windows, proceso

¿Hay algo documentado, o sabéis por experiencia, cómo se puede matar un proceso de forma más rápida?

Tengo dos opciones:

1. Llamando desde mi aplicación a un `taskkill /f /im nombreproceso.exe`
2. Matando el proceso usando `terminateprocess` de la API de Windows, junto con `process32first`.

¿Cuál es más rápida? ¿Hay mucha diferencia? Lo quiero porque estoy haciendo un antivirus.

Comment: Hola Bela, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Has implementado ambas situaciones y creado un benchmark para analizarlo? Con ello sabrás cual es la más rapida y cuanta diferencia tienen. Las preguntas que buscan experiencias personales se consdieran *basadas en opiniones* y son motivo de cierre. Mira [ask] y [help/on-topic]. Un saludo.

Comment: Lo preguntaba porque tampoco sé cóm hacer un benchmark de esa situación, y seguro que hay algo al respecto.

Comment: Crea procesos y matalos con un método u otro midiendo el tiempo que tardan para compararlos

Comment: ¿cómo voy a medir mili/microsegundos? con un cronómetro en mano lo dudo mucho

Comment: Si la diferencia son microsegundos, entonces que importa cual es mas rapido?

Comment: Bela, sugeria que usaras las funciones y caracteristicas del lenguaje para que el propio programa calculara el tiempo de cada metodo.

Comment: @gbianchi Porque para lo que estoy haciendo, importa bastante

Answer (score 0):

Una llamada a `system` **siempre** va a ser más lenta que una llamada a la API de Windows ¿El motivo?

Usar `system` requiere:

1. Levantar un terminal en un proceso independiente
2. Pasarle al proceso una cadena de texto con la orden
3. El terminal debe interpretar la cadena recibida
4. El terminal ejecuta las llamadas a la API de Windows correspondientes
5. El proceso devuelve una respuesta a la aplicación y seguidamente se destruye el proceso.

Mientras tanto, una llamada a la API es... pues eso, una llamada a `system` pero sin los puntos 1, 2, 3 y 5 ... haz cuentas

Por otro lado `taskkill /f` llama a nivel interno a `TerminateProcess`, por lo que la respuesta acaba siendo aun más obvia todavía... `TerminateProcess` es la opción más rápida.

Comment: Gracias, eso era lo que necesitaba, una buena respuesta ;-)

Comment: Si esta, o cualquier otra respuesta, soluciona tu problema no olvides marcarla como solución... si posteriormente aparece otra respuesta mejor podrás cambiar de opción sin compromiso